# Why is my condition that checks diff between two arrays of objects wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

What is wrong in this if condition. I am getting the wrong result. I need to get equal values in these two objects and diff between them.

```js
const firstArr = [{ name: 'tom', age: 22, city: 'Madrid' }, { name: 'Alex', age: 23, city: 'Berlin' }, { name: 'Sara', age: 28, city: 'Paris' }, { name: 'Rash', age: 20, city: 'Dubai' } ];
const secondArr = [{ name: 'tom', age: 22, city: 'Madrid' }, { name: 'Alex', age: 27, city: 'Berlin' }, { name: 'Hary', age: 29, city: 'London' }, ];

for (let i = 0; i < firstArr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < secondArr.length; j++) {
    if (firstArr[i].name == secondArr[j].name) {
      console.log('eq', firstArr[i].city, secondArr[j].city)
    }
    if (firstArr[i].name != secondArr[j].name) {
      console.log('not found in second array', firstArr[i].city)
    }

    if (secondArr[j].name != firstArr[i].name) {
      console.log('not found in first array', secondArr[j].city)
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: What you want to do and what is expected output ?

Comment: Your second two conditions are identical `tom != Alex` vs `Alex != tom` you're just logging different cities.

Comment: I need tow compare these tow arrays. expected output: In first if condition ('Madrid','Berlin'). In second if condition ('Paris' ,'Dubai'). In third if condition ('London').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I loop the first array first and find matches in second array. If there is a match, diff is displayed. If there is no such match, then the correct text is being displayed. An array is built along the way, which is used to simplify the loop on the second array.

```js
const firstArr = [{ name: 'tom', age: 22, city: 'Madrid' }, { name: 'Alex', age: 23, city: 'Berlin' }, { name: 'Sara', age: 28, city: 'Paris' }, { name: 'Rash', age: 20, city: 'Dubai' } ];
const secondArr = [{ name: 'tom', age: 22, city: 'Madrid' }, { name: 'Alex', age: 27, city: 'Berlin' }, { name: 'Hary', age: 29, city: 'London' }, ];

let names = [];

for (let first of firstArr) {
    let matches = secondArr.filter((second) => (first.name === second.name));
    if (matches.length) {
        console.log('eq', first.city, matches[0].city)
    } else {
        console.log('not found in second array', first.city);
    }
    names.push(first.name);
}

for (let second of secondArr) {
    if (names.indexOf(second.name) === -1) console.log('not found in first array', second.city);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you compare each element of the first array with each element of the second array. You could instead use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to filter the arrays and to find the intersection resp. difference. Then you can map the objects to the city names.

```js
const firstArr = [{ name: 'tom', age: 22, city: 'Madrid' }, { name: 'Alex', age: 23, city: 'Berlin' }, { name: 'Sara', age: 28, city: 'Paris' }, { name: 'Rash', age: 20, city: 'Dubai' } ];
const secondArr = [{ name: 'tom', age: 22, city: 'Madrid' }, { name: 'Alex', age: 27, city: 'Berlin' }, { name: 'Hary', age: 29, city: 'London' }, ];

function intersect(lhs, rhs) {
  return lhs.filter(el => rhs.some(el2 => el.name === el2.name)).map(el => el.city);
}

function diff(lhs, rhs) {
  return lhs.filter(el => rhs.every(el2 => el.name !== el2.name)).map(el => el.city);
}

console.log(intersect(firstArr, secondArr));
console.log(diff(firstArr, secondArr));
console.log(diff(secondArr, firstArr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const firstArr = [{ name: 'tom', age: 22, city: 'Madrid' }, { name: 'Alex', age: 23, city: 'Berlin' }, { name: 'Sara', age: 28, city: 'Paris' }, { name: 'Rash', age: 20, city: 'Dubai' } ];
const secondArr = [{ name: 'tom', age: 22, city: 'Madrid' }, { name: 'Alex', age: 27, city: 'Berlin' }, { name: 'Hary', age: 29, city: 'London' }, ];

var eq = [], uniqueInFirst = [], uniqueInSecond = [];

for (let i = 0; i < firstArr.length; i++) {
  var secondArrCities = Object.values(secondArr).map ((obj) => {return obj.city})
  
  if (secondArrCities.includes(firstArr[i].city)) { 
    eq.push(firstArr[i].city) 
  } else {
    uniqueInFirst.push(firstArr[i].city)
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < secondArr.length; i++) {
  var firstArrCities = Object.values(firstArr).map ((obj) => {return obj.city})
  
  if (!firstArrCities.includes(secondArr[i].city)) { 
    uniqueInSecond.push(secondArr[i].city) 
  }
}



console.log(eq)
console.log(uniqueInFirst)
console.log(uniqueInSecond)
```